# My drop down div isn't visible

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am working on a online shopping website.
This is a div that will display the item and the image should be also used from database.

Help me!

This is the code by which I am trying to fetch the data from mysql database created on phpmyadmin and construct this div.

The problem is that I can't see any output

```
<?php
            include "connect_database.php";
                $sql="SELECT * FROM product";
                $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
                $rows=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
                while ($rows=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                    echo "<div class='item'>
                               <img class='image' src='".$rows["image"]."'><br/>
                                  <span>".$rows["product_name"]."</span><hr/>
                                  <span>".$rows["model_no"]."</span><hr/>
                                  <span>Rs ".$rows["amount"]."</span>
                           </div>
                    ";    
                }
        ?>
```

Comment: How are we supposed to debug this for you? You need to go through the code and find out which part is broken. It could be the connection to the database, the query, there could be no results, to name but a few options.

Comment: add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top to debug..it will help you by pointing out the errors in your code.

Comment: no errors are being reported

Comment: Are you sure you have added products..try executing the query in phpMyadmin..

Comment: Fixed some grammar and formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call `mysqli_fetch_assoc` first before the while loop. That call reads the first row, but the result is not used. After that, the while loop kicks in and processes and outputs the rest of the rows. If you have only one row, you won't see anything.

So you can try this, with that line removed.

Note that I renamed `$rows` to `$row`. This isn't necessary, but since the variable will contain data of only one row, I think this name is better. It will help you understand the code better if you need to change it later.

```
<?php
         include "connect_database.php";
            $sql="SELECT * FROM product";
            $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
            while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                echo "<div class='item'>
                           <img class='image' src='".$row["image"]."'><br/>
                              <span>".$row["product_name"]."</span><hr/>
                              <span>".$row["model_no"]."</span><hr/>
                              <span>Rs ".$row["amount"]."</span>
                       </div>
                ";    
            }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 echo '<div class="item">
 <img class="image" src="'.$rows['image'].'"><br/>
 <span>"'.$rows["product_name"].'"</span><hr/> <span>"'.$rows['model_no'].'"</span><hr/>
 <span>Rs "'.$rows['amount'].'"</span>
</div>
  ';
```

Answer (score -1):

```
     <?php
        include "connect_database.php";
            $sql="SELECT * FROM product";
            $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

            while ($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
                echo "<div class='item'>
                <img class='image' src="<?php echo $rows['image']; ?>"><br/>
                      <span><?php echo $rows['product_name']; ?></span><hr/>
                      <span><?php echo $rows['model_no']; ?></span><hr/>
                      <span>Rs<?php echo $rows['amount']; ?></span>
                       </div>
                ";    
            }
    ?>
```

Comment: Since numeric indexes are not used, this code won't change anything, assuming `MYSQLI_BOTH` is the only change you made. Hard to tell, since you didn't add any explanation.

Comment: i just tried to answer.i m new and i m also learning so i suggest as i know.